# Custom Pagination Display Total Page Numbers Of Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to do custom pagination in wordpress but I do not no how to show Page 1 of 7 for example in my css i have defined.

You can see it here : http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/ at the bottom of page what i am trying to acheive.

I was looking here at the codex but couldnt find how to get the page numbers so i can show 1/7 2/7 3/7 for example ?

```
<div class="pagination">
<ul>
    <li class="previous">
        <a href="">&lt;</a>
    </li>
    <li class="number">
        <a href="">1/7</a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <a href="">&gt;</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I look here but it dont tell me how to get the total pages to show does anybody have an idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current page in which you are now with:

```
$current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
```

Total number of pages for current query:

```
global $wp_query;
$pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

Maybe you must check this article:
[how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin](http://sgwordpress.com/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/)